# WP Job Manager - Job Types - Custom Permalink

Tags: wordpress

This question is WP Job Manager for Wordpress specific.

I activated the plugins native "Job Types" taxonomy and created 2 job types, "Schools" and "Hotels".

I would like to customise the permalink, so it reads the actual name of the job-type.

Bt default the Listing Base URL for all WP Job Manager listings is : /listings/

What I would like to achieve is that from the default:

```
example.com/listings/my-job-listing-1
```

and

```
example.com/listings/my-job-listing-2
```

it would read:

```
example.com/schools/my-job-listing-1
```

and

```
example.com/hotels/my-job-listing-2
```

Would something like this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://mikejolley.com/2013/12/04/use-wordpress-url-manipulation-functions/

Remove the current link arguments with `remove_query_arg();` and add the new ones. With `add_query_arg();`